# list.append() in python returning null

Tags: python

What is the actual difference between list1.append() and list1+list2 in python??
Along with this, why the following statement return NULL?

```
print(list1.append(list2))
```

{where list1 and list2 are 2 simple list}

Comment: note that `.append` is much different then adding two lists together, however `.extend`ing one list by another is much more similar except it mutates the original list instead of returning a new one.

Comment: `print` would return `None` in 3.x (in 2.x, it is a statement, so it does not return) **no matter what was printed**. Please make sure you understand the difference between displaying a value and returning it.

Answer (score 1):

`list.append()` modifies the object and returns None.

`[] + []` creates and "returns" new list.

https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists

Recommended reading: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/

Answer (score 1):

Returning `None` is a way to communicate that an operation is side-effecting -- that is, that it's changing one of its operands, as opposed to leaving them unchanged and returning a new value.

```
list1.append(list2)
```

...*changes `list1`*, making it a member of this category.

---

Compare the following two chunks of code:

```
# in this case, it's obvious that list1 was changed
list1.append(list2)
print list1
```

...and:

```
# in this case, you as a reader don't know if list1 was changed,
# unless you already know the semantics of list.append.
print list1.append(list2)
```

Forbidding the latter (by making it useless) thus enhances the readability of the language.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = [4,5,6]
>>> a.append(b) # append just appends the variable to the next index and returns None
>>> print a
[1,2,3,[4,5,6]]
>>> a.extend(b) # Extend takes a list as input and extends the main list
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> a+b # + is exactly same as extend
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Answer (score 0):

When you print a function, you print what it returns and the append method does not return anything. However your list now has a new element. You can print the list to see the changes made.

`list1 + list2` means that you combine 2 lists into one big list.

`list1.append(element)` adds one element to the end of the list.

Here's an example of append vs +

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = [4,5,6]
>>> a + b
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>>
>>> a.append(b)
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6]]
```